# Flutter TextFormField initial value not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set an initial value if one is created on my text form field.  When I run my code:

```
final apiField = TextFormField(
  controller: apiFieldController,
  initialValue: _read().toString(),
  obscureText: true,
  style: style,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
      hintText: "API Key",
      border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
);

_read() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//Return String
String stringValue = prefs.getString('apiKey') ?? '';
return stringValue;
}
```

I get the following error:

`package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart: failed assertion. initial value == null || controller == null is not true`

I'm unsure where I'm stuck at.  I do see the controller being initialized.  I believe my _read() method has an issue, but it does return a string.

Comment: wrap with FutureBuilder and provide initial value as ""

Answer (score 7):

Maybe because you set a controller and an initial value. You have to set only one of these properties. Or an initial value or a controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
Map<String, String> map = {
    'Name': '',
};
```

***Inside*** **Widget build(BuildContext context)**

```
 Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        key: map['Name'].isEmpty
          ? Key('Name')
          : Key(map['Name']),
        initialValue: map['Name'],
        onSaved: (value) {
          map['Name'] = value.trim();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either establish the initialValue in the TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  initialValue: "Initial String",
```

OR you can establish it with the TextEditingController:

```
TextEditingController(text:"Initial String");
```

But you can't do both, that will result in a field assertion error:

```
Failed assertion: line 196 pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.
```

I prefer to set the controller with an initial value in initState of the widget holding the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read()` return `Future<string>` instead of string.
You need to set `initial value` **directly** to controller with `setState` method

Also I recommend to install static analyses to your project to avoid such issues
https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: ok i'm new to flutter and don't really understand. so i'll continue to learn

Comment: flag answer if it helps

Comment: Check link https://flutter.institute/run-async-operation-on-widget-creation/